# Rebalancing the data in array to make all same values

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I want to rebalancing the data in array to make all element same value. For example

Before:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 2
)
```

After:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 2
)
```

Another example 
Before:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 2
)
```

After:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 2
)
```

With PHP language, anyone have idea how to do that?.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to do it:

```
<?php
$a = [2, 4, 1, 2];

$sum = array_sum($a);
$len = count($a); 
$r = $sum % $len;
$q = ($sum - $r) / $len;
$res = [];
for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++)
    $res[] = $i < $r ? $q + 1 : $q;

var_dump($res);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution making use of PHP features. Note the idiom on the last line.

```
<?php
$arr = [6,4,9,3,8,2,1,5];

// Calculate the total of the array elements
$sum = array_sum($arr);
$len = count($arr); 

// Using integer division and modulo arithmetic calculate the average and remainder
$avg = intdiv($sum,$len);
$rem = $sum % $len;

// Create a result array and fill with the average
$result = array_fill(0,$len,$avg);

// Spread the remainder over the first few elements.
while($rem){$result[--$rem]++;}

var_dump($result);
?>
```

Example: https://3v4l.org/nY2Fo

Answer (score 1):

You can keep reducing the sum and the array count as you iterate to avoid tracking the modulus.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/iF0iE))

```
$array = [2, 4, 1, 2];
$sum = array_sum($array);
$count = count($array);
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $i => $notUsed) {
    $sum -= $result[] = ceil($sum / ($count - $i));
}
var_export($result);
// [3, 2, 2, 2]
```

Or slightly rearranged as: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/P8pdO))

```
$result = [];
for (
    $sum = array_sum($array), $count = count($array);
    $count;
    --$count
) {
    $sum -= $result[] = ceil($sum / $count);
}
var_export($result);
```

Or, again, with a different loop: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kGAGB))

```
$array = [2, 4, 1, 2];
$sum = array_sum($array);
$count = count($array) + 1;

$result = [];
while (--$count) {
    $sum -= $result[] = ceil($sum / $count);
}
var_export($result);
```